# AnglePath choose a stating point with and angle

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to draw some line in a graphics. For each line I have a starting point a length and an angle.

I'm trying to draw those lines using AnglePath function. However, I can't choose a starting point with a radius and an angle. I read the documentation, but there's no example using the combination angle/radius with a starting point.

```
Line[AnglePath[{{1,1}}]]
```

The code above draw a line of radius 1 with an angle of 1 rad.

For example

```
Line[AnglePath[{1,1}, {0.3}]]
```

change the starting point to {1,1} with an angle of 0.3 rad, but I can't control all the parameters(starting point, angle and radius).

Comment: `For each line I have a starting point a length and an angle` : Please upload this information.

Answer (score 1):

starting point `{1,1}`, radius `2`, angle `π/3`.

```
Graphics[{Red, Line[AnglePath[{1, 1}, {{2, π/3}}]]}]
```

The same as

```
Graphics[Line[{{1, 1}, {1, 1} + 2*AngleVector[π/3]}]]
```